# knockout.js and applying bindings twice with version 2.3.0

Tags: knockout.js

I upgraded to knockout.js 2.3.0 and now I am getting the error `Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element`. An apply bindings is happening a second time with `renderTemplate` below, anyway to fix it?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.eventsMap = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var accessor = valueAccessor();
            ko.renderTemplate(accessor.name, accessor.data, {}, element, 'replaceChildren');
        }
    };


<div id="events-template" data-bind="eventsMap: { data: eventsMap.currentLocation, name: 'event-template'}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="event-template">
    <!-- ko if: $data -->
    <div><b data-bind="html: $data.City"></b></div><hr/>

    <div class="events-list" data-bind="with: $data.Events">
        <div data-bind="foreach: { data: $data, afterRender: function(element, index, data) { $(element).filter('.span12').find('a[rel!=nofollow]').attr('target', '_blank') }}">
            @Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.Views.Controls.Events)
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may have a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11268863/419956). If you tell Knockout that your binding handler controls bindings of the child elements in the template itself, the error will be gone. So:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.eventsMap = {
        init: function(elem, valueAccessor) { 
            return {controlsDescendantBindings: true};
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var accessor = valueAccessor();

            ko.renderTemplate(accessor.name, accessor.data, {}, element, 'replaceChildren');
        }
    };
```

See the ["before"](http://jsfiddle.net/fmHM8/2/) and [fixed "after" fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmHM8/1/.).